# Is there a better way to create a color picker in Unity C# and NGUI?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a bit of an art program / game in Unity, however I need to create a color picker for the artists who are building things inside it. I am using the NGUI UI system, and I've created a basic sprite with a set of colors on it, along with a custom color input.

However, actually selecting one of those colors accurately is not proving easy. 
I'm currently doing it like this:

```
IEnumerator CaptureTempArea()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    tex = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();


    Vector2 pos = UICamera.lastEventPosition;

    int x = (int)pos.x;

    int y = (int)pos.y;

    Color color = tex.GetPixel(x, y);

    Debug.Log(ColorToHex(color));

    Debug.Log(tex.GetRawTextureData().Length / 1000);

    Destroy(tex);
    tex = null;
}
```

However, there must be a better way to capture -just- the specific area. This does accurately get the colors, however. But it also generates an image - even temporary - that is anywhere from 2 to 8 MB in size before it gets cleared from the buffer. Given the specific UI system, is there a better way to create a color picker, or one that will use less memory?

Comment: why not use a ready solution ? [found here](https://github.com/judah4/HSV-Color-Picker-Unity)

Comment: I've looked at a number of existing solutions. Partly the problem is if any exist for NGUI, they do not seem to be available I'm not using Unity UI..

Comment: oh right right sorry about that.

Comment: The latest version of Unity UI is nice, but it still has some issues I really don't like about it, particularly forcing the whole UI to world center among other things.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just toggle the UI layer visibility on and off in the top-right corner when working with the new Unity UI.

Answer (score 0):

in general, I would optimize some stuff, like avoiding allocating/reading the while texture just to obtain a single pixel, and keeping a live 1x1 texture throughout the entire session...
if your device support it you can also use computebuffer to pass the color value from a shader...
this is how your code should look like (I haven't tested it, just rewritten your code a bit)

```
Texture2D tex;

void Start() {
    tex = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    //get the color printed by calling:
    StartCoroutine(CaptureTempArea());
}

IEnumerator CaptureTempArea() {
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    Vector2 pos = UICamera.lastEventPosition;
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(pos.x, pos.y, 1, 1), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    Color color = tex.GetPixel(0, 0);
    Debug.Log(ColorToHex(color));
}

void OnDestroy() {
    Destroy(tex);
}
```

Comment: Instead of reading pixels into another texture, it might be possible to read the pixels directly from the active render target in [`Graphics.activeColorBuffer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics-activeColorBuffer.html).